# Find the value of the infinite product $\sqrt\frac12\cdot\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt\frac12}\cdot\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt\frac12}}\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

Find $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}}}....\infty$

---

Let $x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}}}....\infty$
$\log x=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}})+....$
I do not know how to solve it further.

Comment: Downvoter please comment.I have given my attempt/try.

Comment: i am not the down voter, but you can do few more steps in few different ways just to show yourself that you really have tried.

Comment: Similar to this one http://functionspace.com/question/64/Infinite-Product-of-Nested-Radicals But you version diverges, perhaps you mistyped something?

Comment: @achillehui That all the factors are $>1$ its not enough to conclude that the product diverges, what matters is that they are increasing (and hence they don't tend to $1$).

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{\cdots}}{2}}$?

Answer (score 7):

Denote the $n$-th factor by $x_n$. The sequence $(x_n)$  is increasing, and
$$
 x_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt\frac{1}{2}} > \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} = 1
$$
Therefore
$$
 x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \ge x_1 x_2^{n-1} \to \infty \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Begin by investigating the sequence
$$x_0:=0,\quad x_{k+1}:=\sqrt{{1\over2}+x_k}\quad(k\geq0)\ .$$
It has a certain limit $\xi$. Knowing $\xi$ draw conclusions about the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\>\prod_{k=1}^n x_k\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} y_n \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_n = \sqrt {\frac {1} {2} + \sqrt {\frac {1} {2} + \cdots + \sqrt {\frac {1} {2}}}},$$ and $$y = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n.$$ We have $$y_{n + 1} = \sqrt {\frac {1} {2} + y_n},$$ which, passing to limit, gives $$y = \sqrt {\frac {1} {2} + y}.$$ We have $y = \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2} + \frac {1} {2}$, which is $> 1$, and that's why $x$ diverges to $+ \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $a =\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $b$ be the expression you are trying to calculate, then $b^2 = a + b$. You can use quadratic equation to finish.